# Unable to load sourcetree

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm still new to sourcetree. Whenever I'm launching a project, I faced the following errors:

1. When i select a project, it will show this error `'git log' failed with code -1:'launch path not accessible"` and
   `'git status' failed with code -1:'launch path not accessible`. When i tried to google it, i can't find any answers avaliable online.

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Zs3.png)
[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8aUU.png)

2. When i tried to clone a repository from a URL, I'm not able to clone it.

[Error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzVAN.png)

Running on
MacOS Catalina: version 10.15.7
Sourcetree: version 4.2.0 (246)
Any help will be appreciated. Many thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

The following solution solved my problem, when eventually Sourcetree loses git configuration.

> Try switch between system Git and Embedded in Sourcetree Preferences / Git

Source: [Atlassian Sourcetree For Mac Jira](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-7530)

Comment: If your options are "Reset to Embedded Git" and "Use System Git", you can just select "Use System Git" and it will reset the path. You don't have to switch to embedded, or go back and forth between them.